# My Javascript function keeps running/looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that I am trying to run on a SharePoint page.  This is for an HTML form Web part.  When the page is loaded i would like to automatically set the default value to "blank".  I am VERY new to javascript, but I needed this done immediately so I took to google for some assistance.  I was able to find this script and made modifications to it.  Please help find what I am doing wrong, the page keeps refreshing until it times out.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">



<tr>

    <td align="left">

         <span class="CCSPDDLLabel">For Legacy vs Spectrum :</span>

<select name="LegacyVsNew" onchange="LegacyVsNewChangeCategory(this)">                            
<option value="New" selected="selected">New</option>
<option value="New">New</option>        
<option value="Legacy">Legacy</option>
</select>   

               </td>

               </tr>

</table>



<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var fieldName = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var fieldNameValue = fieldName.options[fieldName.selectedIndex];
var fieldNameText = fieldName.options[fieldName.selectedIndex].text;



LegacyVsNewChangeCategory();

function LegacyVsNewChangeCategory()
    {


        if(fieldNameValue.value)    
            _SFSUBMIT_();


    else 
            location.href="/features/custom-filter-html-form"
    }


</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm very curious - Which part of the script did you think was going to default values to blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the page is loaded i would like to automatically set the default value to "blank".

You have the first option selected by default.

```
<option value="New" selected="selected">New</option>
```

Try this instead:

```
<option selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="New">New</option>        
<option value="Legacy">Legacy</option>
```

**But even taking the step above, you will always have a value selected, and you're running a redirect in the function anyway**.

You're calling your function on page load. The function checks to see if something is selected, and either runs `_SFSUBMIT_();` if something is selected, otherwise it runs a redirect. Being that your page starts with something selected, it will continously run `_SFSUBMIT_();`. If it doesn't have a selected value, it will just immediately redirect you.

**JSFiddle to demonstrate:** https://jsfiddle.net/syg0wv82/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  If i remove LegacyVsNewChangeCategory(); then the function will not run when the page loads, which i want it to do. I just want it to run once when the page loads so i that i can set my value.  The _SFSUBMIT_(); is submitting the SharePoint page.

Comment: But on page load, you're telling it to either re-direct, or do `_SFSUBMIT_();`. Nothing in your javascript is setting the values to anything.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. So is there a way that I can make this run once on page load?  These drop downs are being used to set a filter value.  So I want on page load the filter to be blank (this will display no results instead of all).

Comment: Well for now, remove the value for the selected option like I have above. Additionally, you will need to modify the `if` statement to look for a selected index *greater than 0*, meaning "not the first option (Select...)". This will now make your function fall into the `location.href` redirect. If you don't want this to happen, I'd remove the else case altogether. 

**I've made you a JSFiddle to elaborate:** https://jsfiddle.net/syg0wv82/